# How can I parse specific parts of my AJAX array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I used AJAX to send back an array with many variables worth of data to my page to have displayed. The array looks something like this right now:

```
    {"dateName":"05/18/2016","hour1":null,"hour2":null,"hour3":null,"hour4":null,"hour5":null,"hour6":null,"hour7":null,"hour8":null,"hour9":null,"hour10":null,"hour11":null,"hour12":null,"hour13":null,"hour14":null,"hour15":null,"hour16":null,"hour17":null,"hour18":null,"hour19":null,"hour20":null,"hour21":null,"hour22":null,"hour23":null,"hour24":null}
```

Now I am displaying the parts of the array in my data boxes using

```
            //AJAX Data
            success: function(data) {
            var array = data.split(",");
            $("#date").html(array[0]);
            i = 0;
                while (i < 25) {
                $("#hour"+i).html(array[i]);
                i++;
                }
```

This displays data that looks like this on my webpage

> "hour1":"sleep"

As you can see, the variable name in quotes and the variable value that was passed through ajax. But I only want

> sleep

displayed (no quotes, no variable) . How do I get the variable name and quotes out of my displayed data?

Thank you so much!

Comment: True arrays are notated using square brackets and don't use named indexes. Your hours should be in an array FYI. Also you should be using `JSON.parse` to parse your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
       // $("#div1").html(result);


        var parsed = JSON.parse(result);
        alert(parsed["hour1"]);
    }});
```

Comment: success: function(data) {
              var array = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#date").html(array["dateName"]);
            i = 0;
                while (i < 25) {
                $("#hour"+i).html(array["hour"+i]);
                i++;
                }

Comment: var parsed = JSON.parse(result); was exactly what I needed! Great fix!

Answer (score 0):

```
          //AJAX Data
            success: function(data) {
            var hour = "hour";
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
              hour += i;
              console.log(data.hour)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
   var json_obj =JSON.parse(data)
   $("#date").html(json_obj['datename']);
   i = 0;
   while (i < 25) {
     $("#hour"+i).html(json_obj['hour'+i]);
     i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through the help of a few of you awesome members here at stackexchange I have finally figured out how to send an ajax, call back multiple variables, and arrange them cleanly on my page. Attached is my code, I hope that this can help future users.

```
//SEND MULTIPLE DATA THROUGH AJAX
        <script>
        function ajax() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "changeDate.php",
                data: {
                    amount: changeDate,
                    loginName: "benjamin_lawson"
                },

                success: function(result) {
                    //make array out of data
                    var array = JSON.parse(result);
                    $("#date").html(array[0]);

                    i = 0;
                    while (i < 25) {
                        //call array information for parts
                        $("#hour"+i).html(array[i]);
                        i++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <?php

            //create the array
                $response_arr = array();

            //add your variables to the array
                $response_arr[] = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+" . $amount . " day"));
                $response_arr[] = $row[$dateName];      

            //echo the final array to be sent to your ajax
                echo json_encode($response_arr);

        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.parse to convert the string to json obj :

> json_obj=JSON.parse(data)
>   $("#date").html(json_obj['']);